# Filtering inside a FOREACH block by a condition value calculated inside the same block in PIG

Tags: foreach, apache-pig, conditional-statements

I have a log dataset, and I need to filter out all the log entries for an equipment after a failure (Action = 2).

In this example:

```
EquipId, ScvId, Action, TimeStamp
Ag,01,1,14-01-01 0:00:01
Ag,01,1,14-01-02 0:00:01
Ag,01,2,14-01-03 0:00:01
Ag,01,1,14-01-04 0:00:01
Ag,01,1,14-01-05 0:00:01
Ag,01,2,14-01-06 0:00:01
Ag,01,1,14-01-07 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-01 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-02 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-03 0:00:01
Ra,01,2,14-01-04 0:00:01
Fe,01,2,14-01-03 0:00:01
Fe,01,1,14-01-03 0:00:02
Fe,01,1,14-01-04 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-05 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-04 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-05 0:00:01
```

The expected output would be

```
Ag,01,1,14-01-01 0:00:01
Ag,01,1,14-01-02 0:00:01
Ag,01,2,14-01-03 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-01 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-02 0:00:01
Ra,01,1,14-01-03 0:00:01
Ra,01,2,14-01-04 0:00:01
Fe,01,2,14-01-03 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-05 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-04 0:00:01
Lu,01,1,14-01-05 0:00:01
```

I was trying to program it in a single FOREACH block like this:

```
rawData = LOAD './test.csv'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (equipId:chararray, svcId:chararray, action:chararray, date:chararray);

equipDataGrp = GROUP rawData BY equipId;

minFail = FOREACH equipDataGrp {

    actionFail = FILTER rawData BY action == '2';
    minFailDate = MIN(actionFail.date);
    prevActionsFail = FILTER rawData BY date <= minFailDate;


    GENERATE group as equipId, FLATTEN(prevActionsFail.date);

};
```

and I get the following error:

```
2014-03-05 11:08:11,720 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: 
<line 36, column 28> Invalid field reference. Referenced field [date] does not exist in schema: .
```

If I hardcode the date as:

```
minFail = FOREACH equipDataGrp {

    actionFail = FILTER rawData BY action == '2';
    minFailDate = MIN(actionFail.date);
    prevActionsFail = FILTER rawData BY date == '14-01-03 0:00:01';


    GENERATE group as equipId, FLATTEN(prevActionsFail.date);

};
```

I get response:

```
(Ag,14-01-03 0:00:01)
(Fe,14-01-03 0:00:01)
(Ra,14-01-03 0:00:01)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compute the time of failure and distribute that to all records for the equipment ID.  Then you can filter the records with timestamps later than that:

```
rawData = LOAD './test.csv'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (equipId:chararray, svcId:chararray, action:chararray, date:chararray);

equipDataGrp = GROUP rawData BY equipId;

/* Expand out into all records again, appending the earliest failure time */
minFail = FOREACH equipDataGrp {
    actionFail = FILTER rawData BY action == '2';
    GENERATE FLATTEN(rawData), MIN(actionFail.date) AS failTime;
};

notYetFailed = FOREACH (FILTER minFail BY date <= failTime) GENERATE equipId .. date;
```

Comment: Thank you! We implemented it this way